# Is it possible to create a pull request with AWS Code Commit through Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, version-control, pull-request

My team wants to implement code reviews into our development process. Our team uses AWS CodeCommit through AWS Web Tools on Visual Studio. My question is can you create a pull request through Visual Studio? From my research we've only been able to create them through AWS cli / command line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it’s not possible from within Visual Studio. The integration was written before CodeCommit  supported pull requests and hasn’t been updated since support was added.

You would have to create them through the Cli/SDK or console.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2020 that is possible! See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ide-vs.html